# How to Add Days to Datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have 2 date pickers txtbookin and txtcompleted

And I have one more textbox named txtnoofdays which will accept only integers

My Requirement:

If I key-in any integers in txtnoofdays textbox, ontextchanged event I want to add txtnoofdays to txtbookin and display corresponding Date in txtcomplete..I am writing as below..
but its adding to month instead of date..my system date format dd/MM/yyyy...

```
 var dt1 =Convert.ToDateTime(txtbookindate.Text);
        var dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtcompleted.Text);
        var dt3 = dt1.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(txtnoofdays.Text));
        txtcompleted.Text = dt3.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: What programming language is this? Please add a tag.

Comment: What is the value of "txtnoofdays.Text" in your case. If its more than number of days in a particular month it will increase the value of month instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the overloaded method of `Convert.ToDateTime(string, IFormatProvider)` to get dates converted correctly to your locale settings...

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");     
var dt = Convert.ToDateTime(txt.Text, culture);
```

Do it for both datetimes texts...